# More effective concurrent solution

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I'm taking a class on concurrency right now and I've finished my first (stupidly simple) project and now I want to actually make it useful.

In my code, I'm doing a binary search through an array for every value of a second array. For each value in the second array, I'm spawning a thread. This turns out to be slower than a sequential solution, so my thought process was that I'd spawn a small number of threads and pass them a new key every time they have finished executing.

There's a couple problems I have. The first is, how do I get threads to exit when there are no more keys?

how do I pass new keys?

how do I get the threads to not execute with the old keys, while waiting for the new ones (I've been reading about conditional waits and think that's what I need).

Here's my current (ineffective) solution.

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 50000
#define KEY_NOT_FOUND -1
#define KEY_FOUND 0

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 

int binary_search(int *array, int key, int min, int max); 
void *worker(void *arg);

int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t L;
int l_array[ARRAYSIZE * 2];

int main(void)
{
    int r_array[ARRAYSIZE]; 
    int *p;
    pthread_t *threads;
    int ix = 0;
    int jx = 0;

    struct timeval start, stop;
    double elapsed;

    for(ix = 0; ix < ARRAYSIZE; ix++)
    {
        r_array[ix] = ix;
    }
    for(ix = 0; ix < ARRAYSIZE * 2; ix++)
    {
        l_array[ix] = ix + 2;
    }

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(ARRAYSIZE * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (jx = 0; jx < ARRAYSIZE; jx++) {
         p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));  
        *p = r_array[jx];
        pthread_create(&threads[jx], NULL, worker, (void *)(p));
    }

    for (jx = 0; jx < ARRAYSIZE; jx++) {
        pthread_join(threads[jx], NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", count);

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    elapsed = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000+(stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec))/1000000.0;
    printf("time taken is %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}

void* worker(void *arg)
{
    int boolean = 0;
    int key = *((int *) arg);
    boolean = binary_search(l_array, key, 0, ARRAYSIZE * 2);
    if(boolean == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&L);
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&L);
    } 
}

int binary_search(int *array, int key, int min, int max)
{
   int mid = 0;
    if (max < min) return 0;
    else
    {
      mid = (min + max) / 2;
      if (array[mid] > key) return binary_search(array, key, min, mid - 1);
      else if (array[mid] < key) return binary_search(array, key, mid + 1, max);
      else 
        {
        return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: creating 50000 pthreads! BIG NO. `ARRAYSIZE 50000`

Comment: Alright, what's a more reasonable number of threads?

Comment: You may build a thread pool, one thread per core, so 4 or 8 today for a basic desktop

Comment: you can find that out yourself by timing your program. Instead of passing a single element pass the base address of `r_array`(as if it's a queue). Another variable to track the `next_index`. A pThreadMutEx to modify `next_index`.

Comment: Ok, I'm taking both of your advice and modifying the code currently. Since I'm going to have more then one locks I now have to worry about dead locks. I know that one has to set priority to resources and I'm guessing you do that using mutex attributes. Any more pitfalls I should avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: below code is not tested, however it's easy...

- pass the base address of `r_array[]` to worker
- keep a global `next_index`
- define another `pthread_mutex`

PS: as with the number of threads, begin with 2 and progress till you find no difference in throughput. You need to consider all the overheads too..

```
void worker(void *arg)
{
    int* r_arrPtr = (int*) arg;
    int boolean = 0;
    int key =0;[

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pNextIndex_MutEx);
        if (next_index < ARRAYSIZE) {
            key = r_arrPtr[next_index];
            next_index ++;
        } else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&pNextIndex_MutEx);
            return;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pNextIndex_MutEx);

        boolean = binary_search(l_array, key, 0, ARRAYSIZE * 2);
        if (boolean == 1) {
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the indexes you pass to `binary_search`. `max` is `(ARRAYSIZE * 2 -1)`

Comment: So I tested this solution and found that 4 threads lead to no difference. (sometimes it's slower, sometimes it's faster). Thank you very much for the help. =D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to build a thread pool, one thread per core, so 4 or 8 today for a basic desktop.

In application pf the ["Divide and conquer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) strategy, for each thread you give a job with a part of the search. Between the controller and the worker  a "producer/consumer" relationship exists: a blocking queue may be used. The worker waits for a job and the controller enqueues the job.

The "job" may be a structure containing all the information to work.